Optimistic Updates unnecessary Re-rendering
"use client";

import { Input } from "../ui/input";
import { Label } from "../ui/label";
import { Card, CardContent, CardDescription, CardFooter, CardHeader, CardTitle } from '../ui/card';
import { Button } from '../ui/button';
import { UploadButton } from "@/utils/uploadthing";
import { startTransition, useOptimistic, useState } from "react";
import { Textarea } from "../ui/textarea";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import uuid from "uuid-random"
import Project from "../ui/Projects";
import { fetchProjects, generateProjects } from "@/app/api/formServerActions/projects";
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";

interface UploadedFile {
    name: string;
    size: number;
    key: string;
    serverData: null | any;
    url: string;
    customId: null | any;
    type: string;
}

type Project = {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    imageUrl: string;
    liveUrl: string;
    githubUrl: string;
    techUsed: string[];
    description: string;
};


const Projects = () => {
    const { register, handleSubmit, reset } = useForm();
    const [uploadedFile, setUploadedFile] = useState<UploadedFile | null>(null);
    const [techUsed, setTechUsed] = useState<string[]>([]);

    const { data } = useQuery({
        queryKey: ['fetchProjects'],
        queryFn: async () => await fetchProjects(),

    })

    const [optimisticProjects, addOptimisticProjects] = useOptimistic(
        data?.project ?? [],
        (state, newProject: Project) => [...state, newProject]
    );



    const handleTechUsedChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const { value } = event.target;
        setTechUsed(value.split(',').map((tech) => tech.trim()));
    };







    const onSubmit = async (data: any) => {
        const imageUrl = uploadedFile?.url || '';
        const id = uuid()
        const finalData = {
            ...data,
            imageUrl,
            techUsed,
            id,
        };


        await startTransition(() => {
            addOptimisticProjects(finalData);
        });
        console.log(optimisticProjects)
        await generateProjects(finalData)
        reset();
        setUploadedFile(null)
    };

    console.log(optimisticProjects)
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                <Card>
                    <CardHeader>
                        <CardTitle>Projects</CardTitle>
                        <CardDescription>
                            Make changes to Projects. Click save when you&#39;re done.
                        </CardDescription>
                    </CardHeader>
                    <CardContent>
                        <div className="space-y-6 p-6 rounded-lg shadow-lg">
                            <div className="flex gap-4 items-end">
                                <div className="space-y-2 w-full">
                                    <Label htmlFor="title">Project Title</Label>
                                    <Input
                                        id="title"
                                        {...register("title")}
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div className="space-y-2 w-full">
                                    <Label htmlFor="liveUrl">Live URL</Label>
                                    <Input
                                        id="liveUrl"
                                        {...register("liveUrl")}
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="space-y-2 w-full">
                                <Label htmlFor="githubUrl">Github Url</Label>
                                <Input
                                    id="githubUrl"
                                    {...register("githubUrl")}
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="space-y-2 w-full">
                                <Label htmlFor="upload">Upload Project Image</Label>
                                <div className="flex items-center justify-center">
                                    <UploadButton
                                        className="bg-blue-500 w-full justify-start flex-row gap-4 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-lg shadow hover:bg-blue-600 transition-colors duration-300"
                                        endpoint="productImage"
                                        onClientUploadComplete={(res: UploadedFile[]) => {
                                            if (res && res[0]) {
                                                setUploadedFile(res[0] as UploadedFile);
                                            }
                                        }}
                                        onUploadError={(error: Error) => {
                                            alert(`ERROR! ${error.message}`);
                                        }}
                                    />
                                </div>
                                {uploadedFile && (
                                    <div className="mt-4 p-4 rounded-lg shadow-md">
                                        <p><strong>File Name:</strong> {uploadedFile.name}</p>
                                        <p><strong>File Size:</strong> {(uploadedFile.size / 1024).toFixed(2)} KB</p>
                                        <a
                                            href={uploadedFile.url}
                                            target="_blank"
                                            rel="noopener noreferrer"
                                            className="text-blue-500 hover:underline"
                                        >
                                            View File
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                )}
                            </div>
                            <div className="space-y-2 w-full">
                                <Label htmlFor="projectDesc">Project Description</Label>
                                <Textarea
                                    id="projectDesc"
                                    {...register("description")}
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="space-y-2 w-full">
                                <Label htmlFor="techUsed">Project TechStack</Label>
                                <Input
                                    id="techUsed"
                                    onChange={handleTechUsedChange}
                                />
                                <p className="text-sm text-gray-500">Separate each tech with a comma</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </CardContent>
                    <CardFooter>
                        <Button type="submit">Save changes</Button>
                    </CardFooter>
                </Card>
            </form>

            <Project projects={optimisticProjects} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default Projects;




I am trying to use the Optimistic updates in my app and i adds the updates but for a short time after some time it will remove the updates from the array enter image description here as you can see here ,
At first it gives me old fetched array then i add a value to it it keeps value for some time then removed it ,
How i can fix it
